# NameError: name 'sklearn' is not defined

Tags: python, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I am running a feed forward neural network and want to get a confusion matrix with the line

```py
sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix(goldLabel_array, predictions, sample_weight=None, labels=None)
```

But when I am running it, it gives me the error message in the headline.
I installed scikit-learn and sklearn. WhenI am running 'pip list', sklearn is listed, but with the version 0.0. When I am running conda install sklearn it gives me the following:

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - sklearn

Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/loopbio/win-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/loopbio/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

Comment: Have you tried `conda install -c anaconda scikit-learn` or `conda install scikit-learn`? I know that you `import sklearn` but the package itself is called `scikit-learn`.

Comment: Do you mean this [sklearn](https://pypi.org/project/sklearn/)? In which case this *is* scikit-learn. Have you remembered to import the module?

Comment: When I run conda install -c anaconda scikit-learn, it gives me 'You probably need to delete and re-download or re-create this file.  Message from libarchive was:\n\nCould not unlink (errno=22, retcode=-25, archive_p=2733626229488)')' But I already tried to uninstall it and install it one more time

Comment: Could you post your code?

Answer (score 2):

The error is nothing to do with installing. It is telling you that you have not imported the library into the place you are calling it in your code.

**Edit** You're importing `confusion_matrix` directly, so you need to reference it directly, not via sklearn.

```
confusion_matrix(goldLabel_array, predictions, sample_weight=None, labels=None)
```

and the same with your other calls.

Comment: I imported it by 'from sklearn.metrics import multilabel_confusion_matrix' and 
'from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix'

Comment: If you've imported it as `from sklearn.metric import multilabel_confusion_matrix` then you need to refer to the function in your code as `multilabel_confusion_matrix` not as `sklearn.metric.multilabel_confusion_matrix`.